# Command "window.location.href" not working on HTML (Bootstrap framework)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a university project in which I need to create a simple login screen which redirects the user to another landing page. As I'm new to web programming, I searched some functions and found that the most used command is the `window.location.href`, which simply doesn't work on my code. Here it is:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="validation(this.form)">Sign in</button>
  </form>

<script language = "Javascript">
    function validation(form){
        if(form.inputEmail.value=="user@user.com" && form.inputPassword.value=="user123"){
                window.location.href('form.html');
        } 
        else {
            alert("Invalid e-mail or password.");
        }           
    }
</script>
```

I've already checked the paths, but the only method that works when you enter the valid username and password is the `window.open()`

Comment: Look at your console: `Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href is not a function(…)`

Answer (score 14):

`window.location.href` is a property not a function. Assign the value as an absolute path instead.

```
window.location.href = '/form.html';
```

There is also a function style way of doing this which you might be confusing it with:

```
window.location.assign("form.html");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a function.  Do this instead:

```
window.location.href = 'form.html';
```

Additionally, turn on your browser's debug console to see any JavaScript errors.  In Chrome it will say "Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href is not a function(…)"

Answer (score 0):

Try also this

```
window.location = "form.html";
```