# How Framework7 changes the URL in browser address bar

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I am trying to figure out how Framework7 works for a website development.

Although there is some info and tutorials on the websites and Youtube, I can't find nor understand how I can change the URL's in browser.

Can some please show me the way or some existing tutorial on how links do change in the address bar of a browser.

Thank you

Comment: it seems like a dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011705/command-window-location-href-not-working-on-html-bootstrap-framework/34012190  are you sure that using **window.location.href** is not working?

Comment: No. it has to do something with pushState: true from the Framework7

Answer (score 1):

So in every Framework7 app you have this main app.js where you initialize the app

It beginst with

```
// Initialize your app
var myApp = new Framework7();
```

And then on the website they write about pushState must be set to true, in order to enable History mode

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
pushState: true
});
```

And I was doing it..

But had no luck..

It did not pass my mind that the pages are caching actually...

set `pushstate:true` and do not forget to Ctrl-F5 your browser.)))

Answer (score 1):

In v2 it has been moved under common view parameters

```
app.framework7 = {
  view: {
    pushState: true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this in modern times, Framework7 version 7 - it's changed yet again.

on your view element you set attribute browserHistory

```html
<f7-view main browserHistory browserHistoryInitialMatch />
```

documented here: https://framework7.io/docs/routes#route-options

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie to f7 and had the same question. After googling a bit I've found this on [GitHub](https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7-Vue/issues/234) (thanks to nolimits4web and lizhouyang):

> pushState parameter must be set on view in v2

So in my case I was set it in "/src/app.vue" like this:

```
<!-- Main View -->
<f7-view id="main-view" url="/" main :pushState="true"></f7-view>
```

Now if I click on a link to the About page, the address bar shows this url and I can use the back button of the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/#!/about/
```